# Integration of a matrix by MATLAB

Tags: integration, matrices, matlab

How do I integrate a matrix in MATLAB:

```
A=[1,2;3,4];

B=[2*t;t^2];
```

i.e, how to compute:

```
integral{expm(A*s)*B(s)}ds
```

between the interval $[1,t]$?

The variable $t$ can be a symbolic parameter.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to try this:

```
syms t s;

A   = [1 2 ; 3 4];
Bs  = [2*s; s^2];

R   = int(expm(A*s)*Bs,s,1,t);
```

Let me know if this is helpful to you.

Cheers!

Comment: This is very helpful and thank you.

Comment: You're welcome @SaeedAref